# Elegant way to add dummy records to a view?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view (oracle DB) and want to create another with additional dummy records. The way I was told by a guy here at work is rather unelegant but works:

```
select * from SOME_VIEW
union all select a0,b0,c0,d0... from dual
union all select a1,b1,c1,d1... from dual
...
```

Is there a way to avoid making one union per record and instead make an union with the whole set of records?

Thanks.

Comment: There would be in standard SQL: `(values (1,2,3), (4,5,6),...)` but Oracle still doesn't support this.

Comment: You could create another table with the values and union that. If that is not an option, I'm afraid in Oracle there is no other way than unions from `dual`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm restricted by the licence to create new tables, just have views to work with.

Comment: really! how odd :)

Comment: How are you deciding what the dummy entries should be - are they say 10 rows with a common value + numeric suffix (as your example sort of suggests, if those are supposed to be text literals)? If there's a pattern to them you might be able to generate them with a hierarchical query or recursive CTE. Big 'if' though...

Comment: Most values are constant, just a few fields change with data such as sales amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchical query to add requested number of dummy rows (below 5 rows):

```
select object_id, object_name from user_objects
union all
select level, 'DUMMY '||lpad(level, 2, '0') from dual connect by level <= 5;
```

which gives us:

```
 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME
---------- ---------------------
   4665358 SOME_OBJECT
   4665359 SOMETHING
       ... ...
         1 DUMMY 01
         2 DUMMY 02
         3 DUMMY 03
         4 DUMMY 04
         5 DUMMY 05
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accepts the burden of defining `TYPE`s, you may use the `NESTED TABLES` to collect your data in a single query

```
CREATE TYPE C AS OBJECT (  
   id_num  INT,
   name    VARCHAR2(10),
   trans_date DATE)  
/

CREATE TYPE TC AS TABLE OF C   
/

SELECT id_num, name, trans_date 
FROM TABLE(TC(
--- your data here
C(1, 'aaaa', sysdate),
C(2, 'bbbb', DATE'2019-01-26'),
C(3, 'cccc', DATE'2018-01-01')
---
));

    ID_NUM NAME       TRANS_DATE        
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 aaaa       26.01.2019 12:27:25 
         2 bbbb       26.01.2019 00:00:00 
         3 cccc       01.01.2018 00:00:00
```